# JFreechart image is not created using OpenJDK

Tags: image, jfreechart, java

I have compiled OpenJDK in ubuntu and installed the JRE to another Linux system.

I am creating a Chart image using jFreechart using openjdk and saving it as JPG. The output image is having only the white background and the chart lines are missing. The same code works fine in Windows with openjdk.

1. I guess some dependencies are missing but i am not able to find it. Could any one list the dependencies of openjdk. It has requirement of native libraries in Linux.
2. I am also getting an exception related to Fonts (sun.awt.X11FontManager.getDefaultPlatformFont(X11FontManager.java:779)). What is the default font location for OpenJDK? It is not looking in to the fontconfig.properties file.

Comment: What chart theme? Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 0):

While I don't know how to help with your exact problem, you could consider trying a different Java Charting API. I prefer [XChart](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart), and if you just need a line or scatter chart and PNG format is OK, it would be very easy to just try it out on Ubuntu quickly. Taken from [here](http://xeiam.com/xchart_examplecode.jsp) (Example 1), this is all the code you would need:

```
// Sample Data
Collection<Number> xData = Arrays.asList(new Number[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 });
Collection<Number> yData = Arrays.asList(new Number[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 });

// Create Chart
Chart chart = new Chart(500, 400);
chart.setChartTitle("Sample Chart");
chart.setXAxisTitle("X");
chart.setYAxisTitle("Y");
chart.addSeries("y(x)", xData, yData);

BitmapEncoder.savePNG(chart, "./Sample_Chart.png");
```